# Control de sesiones en php

Tags: php, mysql

** tengo una pequeña duda es que no sé cómo puedo crear un control de sesiones con php y mysql será que ustedes me pueden ayudar a completar mi parte del código, la idea también es que si el usuario no tiene una sesión iniciada no pueda ingresar a ninguna página donde requiera el inicio de sesión muchas gracias y espero que me puedan ayudar con mi pequeña duda  **

```
function validar($usuario, $contrasena){
    $contra = md5($contrasena);
    $sql6=$this->conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and contrasena='$contra'");
    if ($f2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql6)) {
        if ($contra==$f2['contrasena']) {
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$f2['usuario'];
            $_SESSION['contrasena']=$f2['contrasena'];
            

            echo "<script>location.href='../libreria/consultar_compra.php'</script>";
        } 
    }else {
        echo "<script >alert('Usuario o contraseña incorrectos ');
        window.location='../index.php';
        </script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: El código va como texto por favor, además trata de ser mas claro en lo que llevas hecho así como exponer de forma mas puntual los problemas que al momento tengas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para que el usuario sin una sesión iniciada no pueda ingresar a ninguna página puedes usar un método sencillo como este:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
 header('location: index.php');
}else{
 echo 'Bienvenido...';
}
?>
```

Puedes ver como manejar [sesiones aquí](https://diego.com.es/sesiones-en-php)

Comment: Cristian muchas gracias me sirvio una pregunta como puedo hacer para imprimir el nombre del usuario que inicio sesion

Comment: Puedes asignarla a una variable asi $user=$_SESSION['usuario']  e imprimir la variable con:  echo $user.